# Ok, so now my wordpress site pages are giving 404

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, admin, permalinks

the main/home page loads fine, but the other pages give 404 error.  Here is the db url settings:

```
option_name        option_value
siteurl            http://localhost/wpsite/
home               http://localhost/wpsite/
```

so http://localhost/wpsite loads just fine, but lets say theres and about page:

http://localhost/wpsite/about  -    this page gives a 404 error by the xampp local server.

And in wp admin, under pages, the about page is listed there.  So what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `.htaccess` file is not working.

Try to reset the permalinks to default one and then please check once if the other urls are now working fine or not.

Comment: man ur soo wrong...all i had to do was change the permalink structure.  It was set to a different structure than the hardcoded one in pages section.

Answer (score 0):

If the above tips are not working.

Go to settings->permalinks 
Choose custom structure 
paste index.php before post-name

```
/index.php/post-name/
```

and save it.

Hope it works!

Answer (score -4):

All I had to do was change the permalink structure under settings->general section to the structure the current permalinks of the pages have it as.